# FTP clients cannot talk to TCP server I have implemented

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, ftp

I'm implementing my own TCP server. So far I can make a connection, that works fine, I can connect to any client. However when I want to send or receive messages from the client it goes  wrong. The following is a snippet of the last part of my server, where I want to send the message WeLcOmE to my client (I'm using C programming language & Linux as the OS):

```
// Accept a connection request
int clientAddress =  sizeof(client_address); 
int new_socket = accept(door_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address,    
&clientAddress);
if (new_socket < 0) 
    perror("ERROR on accept");

// Receive data from socket, send data to socket
char buff[8] = "WeLcOmE";
send(new_socket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);

// Close socket 
close(new_socket);
close(door_socket);
return 0;
```

- Running my server with a Filezilla Client this is what I get:

> Status:    Resolving address of ubuntu
>   Status:    Connecting to 127.0.1.1:3471...
>   Status:    Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Response:    WeLcOmE
>   Error:    Could not connect to server
>   Status:    Waiting to retry...
>   Status:    Resolving address of ubuntu
>   Status:    Connecting to 127.0.1.1:3471...
>   Status:    Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection
>   refused by    server".
>   Error:    Could not connect to server

- Running my server with the ftp Linux built-in client I get:

> ftp> WeLcOmE421 service not available remote server has closed connection

I don't understand why is this happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The FileZilla log clearly shows that it received the "WeLcOmE" message.  Then your code closes the connection socket and the main listening socket and returns from the function.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Ouch! You might want to add some error checking to the return value of `send`. And what makes you think that a server will honour a message saying `"WeLcOmE"`? e.g., If you sent this to a http server, what sort of response or content do you think would be 'served' up?

Answer (score 2):

As you have yourself stated, you have implemented a "TCP" server. All the server does is that it sends the "WeLcOmE" string to any TCP client that connects to the server.

If you connect with an FTP client to the server, the client gets the "WeLcOmE" string, and as that does not conform to the FTP protocol specification, the client errors.

The same would happen, if you connect with any other client that uses a specific protocol, e.g. a web browser [HTTP], a terminal client [SSH or Telnet], etc.

Now the question is, what you are trying to achieve:

- Either you want to implement an FTP server. For that you need to read the FTP specification and implement your server according to it. That's an immense task and in general you do not want to do that. You better take an existing implementation. Either an FTP server library and build your custom FTP server on it. Or take a complete open source FTP server and customize it to your needs.
- Or you just play with your toy TCP server and you want to test it. For that use any TCP client that can work in "raw" mode by reading from the socket and just displaying what it gets, without trying to interpret the data in any way. You can use [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) in a "raw" connection mode. See section [Making raw TCP connections](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-rawprot) in PuTTY documentation.